How to install Monaco editor into a WPF app
I want to install Monaco editor into a WPF app, I Tried looking the issue up on youtube but nothing came up.
I've tried installing  it like I normally would on Windows Forms App but  all it did was come up with a bunch of errors.

Others will not know what you have done when you write "I've tried installing it like I normally would on Windows Forms App". You need to explain step by step what you have done and the error message you got. You wrote that it can be done in Window Forms. Can you share a link explaining how that is done ?

Monaco is a "code editor" and has nothing in particular to do with WPF.
